# Creating an ios 15 device in xcode 12

Tags: xcode, xcode12.5

Is it possible to create an ios15 device in xcode 12.5.1?

I think I'm willing to upgrade to latest of 12.x - not sure how...

but I think upgrading to latest might break my app.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Yes, if you have Xcode 13 you can run your app in an iOS 15 simulator using Xcode 12.

Comment: If I have Xcode 13, how can I have Xcode 12 at the same time. Can you please explain.

Comment: Oh, that's no problem. I like to put one of them in a folder in the Applications folder. Try not to run them both at the same time. But running either of them one at a time is fine. That has always been true; you never have to delete the old one just to install the new one.